# How to dump Redis logs to a file target?

Tags: redis, yii2

I'm trying to dump Redis logs to a file target .

```
          'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
          'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'kriss\log\RedisTarget',
                'redis' => 'redis',
                'key' => 'yii_'.date('Y-m-d').'.log',
                'levels' => ['error','info'],
                'dumpFileTarget' => [
                'logFile' => '/var/log/redis/'.'redis_'.date('Y-m-d').'.log',
                ],
                ],

        ],
    ]
```

This is my log config. I'm using Redis-5.0.5 and kriss/yii2-redis-log,  trying to dump redis log to the file target in a daily basis as a cron job. But i'm unable to dump the log.

i'm using https://github.com/krissss/yii2-redis-log for reference . But its not working . Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score -1):

You have to dump the log like this :

```
Yii::error('this is en error');
```

Read The Doc carefully every this is there:

[Doc Link](https://github.com/krissss/yii2-redis-log)